# Unexpected output in Java - Inheritance related

Tags: java

This is my sample program.

```
class parent
{

    void display(int i)
    {
        System.out.println("parent");
    }

}

class child extends parent
{

    void display(byte i)  //Line 0
    {

        System.out.println("child");
        return;
    }

}

class impl
{

    public static void main(String...args)
    {

        parent p = new parent();
        p.display(5); //Line 1
        child c = new child();
        c.display(3); //Line 2

    }

}
```

This is my output.

```
varun@\:~/Desktop/JavaFiles$ java impl
parent
parent
```

I understand Line 1 calls the display() method from the parent and outputs "parent" which is expected.

But I don’t understand why Line 2 calls the display() from the parent instead of the child even though I am not using polymorphic initialization (just a regular initialization of the child class is what I did).

Answer (score 5):

The `display(byte)` method in `child` does not override the `display(int)` method in `parent`. And since 3 is, by default, an `int`, you call the display method in `parent`.

Try `c.display((byte)3)`

Answer (score 4):

The method you've declared in the child class does not override the method in the parent class; one takes an `int` argument while the other takes a `byte` (you can test this by adding `@Override` to the child class method; a compilation error will occur). In your main method, you are calling `display()` by passing an `int` argument, hence the method of the parent class is called.

If you want to invoke `display()` as declared in the child class, you'll need to explicitly pass a `byte` argument:

```
c.display((byte)3);
```

Answer (score 0):

What inheritence??? The child display takes a byte, you are passing an int so the parent display is called.

Answer (score 0):

You are `overloading` the `display()` in `Child` class, not `Overriding`.

Overriding rules

> 1 Arguments    Must not change
>   2 Return type   Can't change except for covariant (subtype) returns
>   3 Exceptions    Can reduce/eliminate. Must not throw new/broader checked exceptions
>   3 Access    Must not be more restrictive. Can be less restrictive.
>   4 Invocation    Which method to call is based on object type, at runtime time

Answer (score 0):

The parameter 3 is considered as an int, not a byte type.